# Unable to open gnome-control-center in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: settings, gnome-control-center

When I attempt to open settings, nothing happens.

In terminal I use the command

```
gnome-control-center
```

And I get the error

```
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: gst_gl_display_egl_new_with_egl_display
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt purge gnome-control-center
sudo apt clean
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

This worked, gnome-control-center dependencies to messed up while purging Nvidia drivers from the system

Answer (score 0):

You could reinstall faulty library by:

```
sudo apt purge libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
sudo apt clean
```

You need to copy all packages that will be removed and install them again.

Installation of my list of removed packages looks as folows:

```
sudo apt install apturl atril budgie-countdown-applet budgie-desktop \
  budgie-desktop-common budgie-desktop-environment \
  budgie-desktop-minimal budgie-dropby-applet epiphany-browser \
  evolution evolution-data-server evolution-plugin-bogofilter \
  evolution-plugin-pstimport evolution-plugins gdm3 geary \
  gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome gnome-calendar gnome-contacts \
  gnome-control-center gnome-core gnome-documents \
  gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-maps gnome-online-accounts \
  gnome-session gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-sushi \
  gnome-todo gnome-user-docs gnome-user-docs-ru gthumb \
  libatrilview3 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libevolution \
  libfolks-eds25 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 \
  libyelp0 midori mutter rhythmbox-plugins shotwell \
  ubuntu-budgie-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk \
  ubuntu-session update-manager update-notifier yelp zenity
```

Also, you could reinstall `gnome-control-center` first (but do not forget to copy removed packages names, removing asterisk at the end of each and installing them again after removing command execution):

```
sudo apt purge gnome-control-center
sudo apt clean
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Additionaly, make sure, you have proper `/etc/apt/sources.list` records:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

If your system contains repositories with newer packages that are not compatible with official repositories, than you could encounter issues like your.

Also, move everything from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` into other backup folder somewhere on your disk.

Then do `sudo apt clean && sudo apt update` and try to reinstall `gnome-control-center` again.

Most likely you've tried to install something that required newer versions of standard gnome packages and added ppa that contained it. It mayby upgraded your existing packages, required for `gnome-control-center` to work correctly.

Comment: I tried both solutions. Got the same error. My list is  

    nautilus-share apturl deja-dup gdm3 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev:amd64 gnome-calendar unity-control-center  gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-initial-setup gnome-online-accounts ubuntu-session gnome-shell gnome-todo gnome-user-guide gnome-user-docs libedataserverui-1.2-2:amd64 shotwell mutter zenity ubuntu-docs yelp libyelp0:amd64 rhythmbox-plugins indicator-bluetooth gnome-control-center libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 update-notifier update-manager ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64

Comment: Show your sources.list editing your question. But remove comments from it